# How to set admin perms for lock/unlock

Tags: python, discord, permissions, bots, nextcord

```
if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.manage_channels:
        await interaction.response.send_message("You dont have permission for this command", ephemeral=True)
```

I don't know what to set this only for admins / owners. Members can lock / unlock channels...

when i try to /lock /unlock as a member he send me message ""You dont have permission for this command" and lock channel

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def lock( interaction, channel : nextcord.TextChannel= None):
    if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.manage_channels:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Vi niste u mogucnosti da koristite ovu komandu!", ephemeral=True)
        if channel is None:
          channel = interaction.response.message.channel
    await channel.set_permissions(interaction.guild.default_role, send_messages= False)
    await interaction.response.send_message('Channel is locked.')

@bot.slash_command()
async def unlock( interaction, channel : nextcord.TextChannel= None):
    if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.manage_channels:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Vi niste u mogucnosti da koristite ovu komandu!", ephemeral=True)
        if channel is None:
          channel = interaction.response.message.channel
    await channel.set_permissions(interaction.guild.default_role, send_messages= None)
    await interaction.response.send_message('Channel is unlocked')
```

here is full code

Comment: Maybe use `commands.has_permissions()`?

Comment: Can you help me where i need to add it? xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [has_permissions()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) to check for special permissions.

In your case, you can implement it like this:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
```

If you want only the owner of the bot to be able to execute a command, use:

```py
@commands.is_owner()
```

Comment: i got error down

Answer (score 0):

```
Ignoring exception in command lock:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M3C4V1C4\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 143, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\M3C4V1C4\Desktop\botina\main.py", line 85, in lock
    await interaction.response.send_message("Vi niste u mogucnosti da koristite ovu komandu")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'response'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M3C4V1C4\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1355, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\M3C4V1C4\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1003, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\M3C4V1C4\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 152, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'response'
```

i got this after i add
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)

Comment: The error here is related to something totally different. You also should not just copy and paste answers as `@bot.command()` was just a general hint on where to put the actual `@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)` as you use slash commands.

Comment: @bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('You can manage messages.')

I trying like this, but does work...